# Black screen on kivy how to fix

Tags: python, kivy

when I try to run the code it just displays a blank screen I tried to find answers everywhere but nothing works
This is my main.py file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.lang import *
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import *
class MyWidgets(Widget):
    pass
kv = Builder.load_file('math.kv')
class Calculator(App):
    def build(self):
    return kv
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Calculator().run()
```

And this is my math.kv file:

```
<MyWidgets>
num: num
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    TextInput:
        id: num
        multiline: False
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        Button:
            text: '1'
            font_size: 25
        Button:
            text: '2'
            font_size: 25
        Button:
            text: '3'
            font_size: 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an indent error in `build` function. Still, that should have shown some error instead of showing a blank screen. Then in your `.kv` file, I don't know what that `num` is. After removing `num` from `.kv` and correcting indentation error I run the file and it works fine.
Here's the code I used:

.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.lang import *
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import *
class MyWidgets(Widget):
    pass
class Calculator(App):
    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file('math.kv')
        return kv
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Calculator().run()
```

.kv

```
<MyWidgets>

GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    TextInput:
        id: num
        multiline: False
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        Button:
            text: '1'
            font_size: 25
        Button:
            text: '2'
            font_size: 25
        Button:
            text: '3'
            font_size: 25
```

Comment: for some reason I the code still didnt work I made sure to copy the code perfectly it still shows blank screen

Comment: which kivy version are you using? Try using the latest one i.e. v2.0.0

Comment: Im using kivy2.0.0

Comment: im using The Code Editor Atom

Comment: Is it happening with just this app? and is this the full code?

Comment: I will try with notepad++ that is the only other code editor I have, yes this is the full code

Comment: It worked saving it on notepad worked thanks for your help